# Remove some files/dirs from a git branch but keep them in other branches

Tags: git

I would like to know if it exists a direct or easy way for indicating to `git` that certain files should not be in a specific branch but that they are okay in another branch.

For example, I manage some `.clang_complete` files that I wish to track with `git` but my client does not want that they belong to the master branch. Similar situations happen with other types of files and directories.

Any idea, clue?